# How to create LaTeX templates on VS Code to avoid repeating the same codes every time?

Tags: environments

Every time I start editing, I write these words at first:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\title{\large{\textbf{xxx}}}
\author{xxx}
\date{2021}
\maketitle
\section{}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

I may use similar packages and settings every time. So is there any way, like auto signature when sending email, that the software(my editor is VS Code) can generate these codes automatically, so that I can make   some adjustment according to what I want to create, and remain other setting unchanged

Comment: "the software" can (but hopefully not `\title{\large{\textbf{xxx}}}` as `\title` shoudl not contain formatting) but you have not said what software you are using. This is purely a question about your editor, most of which can easily be set to start a new document from some initial template, or simply save that as start.tex and star ta new document by opening that and save to a new name,

Comment: I have updated the page, adding my editor software name.

Comment: mostly it's off topic for this site but look for snipets and texmplates with vs code there are hundreds of pages online with examples eg https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571130/how-can-i-create-templates-for-file-extensions-in-visual-studio-code